# Склонение составных имён существительных

Tags: склонение

Как будет склоняться слово "девочка-подросток"? 
К примеру, я вижу девочку-подростка или девочка-подростка.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это составное существительное, и обе его части будут склоняться так же, как они склоняются по отдельности: "вижу **девочку-подростка**". Иногда составные слова действительно склоняются по-другому, подробнее об этом можно прочесть [тут](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/63-rubric-93).